# Validate required fields that are generated dynamically

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, validation

I am generating input fields dynamically through jsp  based on the data taken from server.

some of those fields can be required fields. How can I validate those fields while submitting form to server.

e.g if fields generated are

```
field1              ----------------

field2 (required)   ----------------

field3              ----------------
```

Comment: What web framework?  What validation framework?

Comment: Spring framework for server side. I want validation in the client side (simple javascript) while submitting. If it can be in dojo then it will also be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With every required field there was a required attribute. So by iterating all fields in javascript and finding required attribute these fields can be validated.

```
var parmCount = parmTable.rows.length - 1;
for(var i = 0; i < parmCount; i++) {
  //logic to get form values
  if(ParamVal.value == '' && attrVal!= null && attrVal == 'required') {
    //validate here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to achieve on the client side, via javascript, using jQuery.

I did this recently by using a special CSS class, something like "requiredField", which I dynamically populated onto form fields for the ones that are required (if all fields are required you don't even need this).

Then you just loop through them using a selector `$(".requiredField")` and perform your validation on every field. You may need to differ your logic based on field type, and then use corresponding selectors to validate, say, checkboxes separately from input fields.

There are tons of examples of how to validate out there, so I'm assuming your question is just about how to dynamically find your fields, not how to mechanically validate them.

Of course, you also could generate a line of javascript for each form field, just like you did to generate the form fields, but that's unnecessary.

Comment: You don't *need* jQuery to implement that strategy, though if you don't know any other way I suppose it helps. The OP can use the [HTML5 getElementsByClassName](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-getelementsbyclassname) or similar and loop over elements with a class of *requiredField* (or whatever) to see if `element.value != ''` or `element.value != element.defaultValue`.